# boto DynamoDB: How can I prevent overwriting items with batch_write?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using [boto's DynamoDB v2](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html) and I'm writing items to a table in batch. However I'm unable to prevent DynamoDB from overwriting attributes of existing items. I'd rather have the process fail.

The table has the following schema:

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table, HashKey, RangeKey

conn = get_connection()
t = Table.create(
        'intervals',
        schema=[
            HashKey('id'),
            RangeKey('start')
        ],
        connection=conn
    )
```

Say I insert one item:

```
item = {
    'id': '4920',
    'start': '20',
    'stop': '40'
}
t.put_item(data=item)
```

Now, when I insert new items with `batch_write`, I want to make sure DynamoDB will not overwrite the existing item. According to [the documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.BatchTable.put_item), this should be achieved with the `overwrite` parameter from the `put_item` method of the `BatchTable` class (which is the one that is used as context manager in the example below)

```
new_items = [{
    'id': '4920',
    'start': '20',
    'stop': '90'
}]

with t.batch_write() as batch:
    for i in new_items:
        batch.put_item(data=i, overwrite=False)
```

However, it doesn't. The `stop` attribute in my example gets a new value `90`. So the previous value (`40`) is overwritten.

If I use the table's own `put_item` method, the `overwrite` parameter works. Setting it to `True` replaces the `stop` value while setting it to `False` results in a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

How can I get that exception when using `batch_write`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this with DynamoDB.  The batch API does not support it.  It is a bug in boto that the `put_item` method of the `BatchTable` object accepts the `overwrite` parameter.  If you check the code, you can see that it does nothing with that parameter.  It is ignored because there is nothing that it can do with it.  DynamoDB just doesn't support this.  At least not yet.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for :). I created an [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3243) at the boto repository.